# Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: color and position arrays must be of equal length

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, build-tools

Hello i'm getting rendering errors in Android studio. Does someone know why this is caused?

My xml:

```
    <!-- ListRow Left side Thumbnail image -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="0dip" >

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/list_image"
         android:layout_width="50dip"
         android:layout_height="50dip"
         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="De Titel van het geweldige bericht"
        android:textColor="#60a926"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Nieuwsbericht subtitel mooi iets ..."
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#9f9e9f"
        android:textSize="10dip" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

    <!-- datum van bericht -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="175dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i'm using the Preview i'm getting this error:

```
"Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: color and position arrays must be of equal length"
```

Is this an `Android Studio` bug or i am doing something wrong ?

I hope someone has the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was caused by using a false gradient style file. Deleting the gradient  file solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 15):

Firstly disable Automatically pick best feature. (You can see on below image)

Then select non preview Api version for rendering

Thats all and worked for me :)

[image]

Also this answer given for fixing problems when using non updated Build Tools Version for rendering. Another way to fix problem :

Open `SDK Manager` and update `Build Tools` version to `Preview Channel` if you want to use `Preview` version of `Build Tools` when rendering.

Answer (score 10):

**Colors used in Gradient Drawable must be of same type**

Meaning colors should be declared as either `hex` format or `attr?color` format in gradient of xml. Mixing them together cause this error.

Example

This will crash

```
 <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="@color/semi_transparent_white"
        android:endColor="@color/semi_transparent_white"
        android:startColor="?attr/colorAccent" <!--Error: Cant mix color and attr -->
        android:type="linear" />
```

This wont

```
 <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="@color/semi_transparent_white"
        android:endColor="@color/semi_transparent_white"
        android:startColor="@color/colorThemeAccent"
        android:type="linear" />
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This problem does seem to be fixed on newer versions of Android (circa 2023). I'd love to know what was the cause of this in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Today is April 14, 2015 (15Apr14). 
'Rendering problems exception raised during rendering'

Here's what worked for me.

My Android SDK manager has downloaded 19, 19.1, 22, and 24.1.2.  22.0.0 is not listed in my SDK manager.  I double clicked 'build.gradle (Module App) under 'Gradle Scripts' in Android Studio and changed the line

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0 to ' 
to
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1'

Then in the drop down menu above the renderer , next to the little Android (called 'Android version to use ...' drop down menu with mouseover) icon I selected 'API 19: Android 4.4.2'.

Rendering worked.

Previously, in the same script target version and build tool versions were set to 19:

buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

targetSdkVersion 19

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by disabeling the preview on a preview version of Android.
Like Android N.

This also helps