# Android Studio 2.1.2 Rendering problems. VectorDrawable_Delegate.nDraw

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, rendering

When attempting to view a preview of your app you may encounter the following...

> Rendering Problems Exception
>
> raised during rendering:
>   android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable_Delegate.nDraw(JJJLandroid/graphics/Rect;ZZ)I

Comment: You can take a look at there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056303/rendering-problems-exception-raised-during-rendering-color-and-position-arrays/36676518#36676518

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering Problems Exception android.graphics.drawable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658009/rendering-problems-exception-android-graphics-drawable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue is resolved by de-selecting the API 23 preview as shown below, select the non Preview option.

[image: Select Android API 23]

Answer (score 0):

I think I am a bit late to answer, but the solutions provided above did not work for me.

The rendering error sure does go away, but the rendering displayed finally after selecting API 23 is incomplete or wrong. 
In my case, the action bar custom theme color and everything vanished.

So, for everyone out there who has a custom theme in their app, here's a solution -

Check if in the XML preview pane, the rendering theme is selected as the one which is associated with your app in the manifest file.

[image]

Select your custom theme in the preview pane, the error will be gone and you will also be able to preview with the latest API (API 24)